# Should I place my Quartz Scheduler tables in a separate database?

Tags: database-design

I am designing a web application that uses Quartz Scheduler to scheduler jobs.

I have Quartz configured to use a JDBCJobStore, so it automatically stores each created job in its tables.

I am wondering if I should create a separate database to store these Quartz tables in, or if I should just store these tables in my web application's main database.

My application's database is not that complex, with only a couple of tables.

I should also note that Quartz allows you to specify a table name prefix for all of its tables, for instance "quartz_".  So if I did store these tables in my application's main database, they would be easily distinguishable from the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My input is that it should be within the application database since it is part of the application. I would put them in a different schema however to keep them separate from the business tables but with only a couple tables, the table prefix should be sufficient too.

Comment: Is it possible to create a schema in anything other than Oracle?  It doesn't look like this is supported in MySQL.

Comment: @Bri - I did it in PostgreSQL... don't know about MySQL.

Comment: Apparently, in MySQL, CREATE SCHEMA is now just a synonym for CREATE DATABASE.  But there used to be a SQL standard many years ago that had a *separate* CREATE SCHEMA command, which allowed you to logically group tables together, into different schemas, and to assign different users different privileges for each schema.  I think I could implement this in MySQL by simply creating a separate user and password for Quartz to access the database, and specify that it can only access the quartz tables, and then create a separate user for my main application that can only access the application tables